# How would one use wget to grab text between specific tags in a webpage?

Tags: wget

How would one use wget to grab text between specific tags in a webpage? A search doesn't seem to turn up anything specific to wget. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something curl is very useful at doing.

Quick untested hak:

```
curl $url | grep $tag | sed -r 's/.*$tag([^<]+).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use wget to download the file, and then search through it with grep or regular expressions (sed) or some kind of outside HTML parser (there are many many many out there). Wget itself can't do this.

I would suggest XMLStarlet or Xidel.

Xidel:

```
xidel http://website.com  -e "css('a')"
```

And just use CSS selector to select the specific tag (putting the selectors inside the `css('{selectors here}')` ).